# How to Set a registry key in a windows form

Tags: vb.net, forms, registry

Hi I'm quite new to this,

I'm wanting to change a reg key string value when I click a button.

```
Private Sub ButtonChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonChange.Click
    Dim SelectedValue = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(
       "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySubKey\Publishing", SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Publishing` is the name of the registry value:

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySubKey", "Publishing", SelectedValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit foolish here as I saw why it wasn't working as soon as I posted. I was going to delete but this might help others. I hadn't put the Key itself in! OMG, sorry world.

```vb
Private Sub ButtonChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonChange.Click
    Dim SelectedValue = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySubKey\Publishing",
                                  "TheKeyWasMissing", 
                                  SelectedValue)
End Sub
```